# Getting Msg 15151, Cannot alter the user 'xxxx', because it does not exist or you do not have permission

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following script and I keep getting errors when it is executed.

```
USE [master]
GO

If Not EXISTS (Select loginname from [master].[dbo].[syslogins]
    Where name = 'xxxx' and dbname = 'xxxx-xxxx')
BEGIN
    CREATE LOGIN [xxxx] WITH PASSWORD=N'xxxxx', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[xxxx-xxxx], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
    ALTER LOGIN [xxxx] ENABLE
END
GO

USE [xxxx-xxxx]
ALTER USER [xxxx] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[db_datareader]
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [xxxx]
ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER [xxxx]
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [xxxx]
GO
```

I have tried several permutations of this script with no success. It does create the login but won't let me alter the "user" or "role" properties. When I can get it to work with no errors, it does not make the changes to the user profile.

Comment: You need to create the user (CREATE USER [xxxx]) before you try to alter it.

Comment: Can you do the `alter user` with the user that executes the script?

Comment: The CREATE USER must be something that the GUI does when creating the login. I used the "Create Script" option in the GUI and it did not show this as a needed command. I moved the CREATE USER into the BEGIN/END block because I want the script to be able to run without errors if it is ran more than once.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing create user before you alter it.

Login - gets you entry to the server
Database User - gets you entry to a particular database

so in your script, add `create user from login ...`

```
USE [xxxx-xxxx]
create user [xxxx] from login [xxxx] <--- this is needed !
ALTER USER [xxxx] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[db_datareader]
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [xxxx]
ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER [xxxx]
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [xxxx]
GO
```

few things :

- sys.syslogins is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-syslogins-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).
- dbatools has cmdlets for [Login and user management](https://dbatools.io/commands/#Login) which you can leverage for automation.

Answer (score 1):

Few Basic ideas.

A login is a security principal, or an entity that can be authenticated by a secure system. Users need a login to connect to SQL Server. You can create a login based on a Windows principal (such as a domain user or a Windows domain group) or you can create a login that is not based on a Windows principal (such as an SQL Server login).

A user is a database level security principal. Logins must be mapped to a database user to connect to a database. A login can be mapped to different databases as different users but can only be mapped as one user in each database. In a partially contained database, a user can be created that does not have a login. For more information about contained database users, see CREATE USER (Transact-SQL). If the guest user in a database is enabled, a login that is not mapped to a database user can enter the database as the guest user.

Logins are distinct from database users. You must map logins or Windows groups to database users or roles in a separate operation. You then grant permissions to users or roles to access database objects.

As mentioned by @Dan Guzman you need to create a user in the database `[xxxx-xxxx]` mapped to the login `xxxx` you are creating.  Then you can run the 2nd section of your code.
Example:

```
CREATE LOGIN WanidaBenshoof   
    WITH PASSWORD = '8fdKJl3$nlNv3049jsKK';  
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
CREATE USER Wanida FOR LOGIN WanidaBenshoof
```

In case you are thinking of contained user.
[Contained Database Users - Making Your Database Portable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable?view=sql-server-2017)

Reference:

1. [Create a Login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-login?view=sql-server-2017)
2. [Create a Database User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-user?view=sql-server-2017)